# Javascript Geoserver make calls to PHP script?

Tags: php, javascript, geoserver

I have a javascript that displays maps using a geoserver running on apache Tomcat. I need to get Information from a database to display tags on the map.But This is where I'm stuck.I have a mysql database which has infomation I need to display. I thought I would use php to access it. But Geoserver or Tomcat doesn't execute php. I tried using JavaBridge to make tomcat run php but that didnt work either.
Is  there any other way I can make geoserver access some information in a database?
I even have django installed but I couldn find any tutorial on how to make the calls ?
I must be muddled with a lot of concepts here.Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to emulate a WMS or WFS server from a Tomcat Servlet to access your DB.

Why do you want to use PHP ?

If you really need so, you could install Apache and emulate a WMS/WFS server with PHP.
Then just use your URL to retrieve data.

Comment: I'm not bound to any scripting language. I just want to get data from my database and make tags out of it using javascript and display on the map.
I'm very new to this and quite did not understand the concept of WMS ,WFS and geoserver. The documentation says that WMS creates a network of map servers. How would this help my application? Please could you explain.

Comment: Then you may just want to launch an ajax call with some data (map bounds, zoom level ...) to a servlet you create that will check DB and send you back the result as an array for example. (You may want to take a look at JQuery or other to send ajax request easily)

Answer (score 0):

A common setup is that you will have GeoServer (Tomcat) running alongside your PHP server (Apache httpd perhaps). In GeoServer you will expose your geospatial data house in MySQL as layers via WMS and/or WFS (These are standardized restful API web services). You will now have a PHP front end writing out to the client browser. Your PHP may get requests for data that can easily be retrieved via a curl request to your GeoServer instance and processed/returned to your client. This is one very specific use case.

Having said that, it sounds like GeoServer, and geospatial web services like WMS and WFS are overkill for your needs. It sounds like you just want to plot some points with a lat/lon on a Google map or something. A simple db query to a table with lat/lon columns and returned to the browser as a json would be sufficient. These would then get plotted on the map as vectors. Note that if you need to plot and display 1000s of vectors the use case becomes more complex because these quickly become a heavy load on a browser and will bring your website to a crawl.